# How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!2^{3n}}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I want to find the following sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!2^{3n}}
$$
However I am not sure that the following computation is true:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n!2^{3n}}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{2^{-3n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(2^{-3})^{n}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(2^{-3})^{n}}{n!}-1=e^{(2^{-3})}-1.
$$
It will be appreciated if anyone check that.

Comment: It's perfectly fine.

Comment: It's correct! Well done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: I think this is best suited for a comment.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: how can we answer this question then ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Not much choice, to be honest. I thought there was a policy on "yes/no" answers but, reading on Meta, it appears to be debated. So, fine by me.